# Getting no answer in Inverse Laplace Transform using Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter online notebook and I'm trying to get the inverse laplace transform the function and I got no answer. I executed the code below:

```
from sympy import *

s=symbols('s')
t=symbols('t')
u=symbols('u')
o=symbols('o')
x=symbols('x')


f3=exp((1/o**2)*(u - sqrt(2*s*o**2+u**2))*x)

inverse_laplace_transform(f3,s,t)
```

However, i got this answer:

[image]

Can you help me how to find the closed form of this answer? Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Where you expecting sympy to know a closed form for this?

Comment: Yes sir @FrankYellin